# How can I filter by a group of individual dates in Google Sheets?

Tags: date, google-sheets

I have a group of individual dates on one sheet, and I'm looking for a quick way to filter by each individual date (not the range) on another sheet.

Group of individual dates

[image: Group of individual dates]

Values I'm trying to filter

[image: Values I'm trying to filter]

Thank you.

I tried separating the dates by comma and putting them into the 'filter by - exact date' part of the filter tool. It will only recognize one date, not multiple.

Answer (score 0):

I'm guessing what you may want to do. But if you want to filter by formula your range according to the dates match your second range you can do something like this:

```
=FILTER (Sheet1!A:O,INDEX(IFERROR (MATCH(Sheet1!A:A,Sheet2!A:A,0))))
```

Change the ranges accordingly. I used sheet 2 as the set of dates you wanted to filter by